# Is it possible to install Kohana libraries for ORM in PHP without using the entire framework?

Tags: php, orm, kohana

In a previous question, I asked about various ORM libraries. It turns out Kohana looks very clean yet functional for the purposes of ORM. I already have an MVC framework that I am working in though. If I don't want to run it as a framework, what is the right fileset to include to just give me the DB and ORM base class files?

Update:

I jumped in and started looking at the ORM source code.. One thing was immediately confusing to me.. all the ORM classes have the class name appended with _CORE i.e. ORM_Core ORM_Iterator_Core, but the code everywhere is extending the ORM class. Problem is, I've searched the whole code base 6 different ways, and I've never seen a plain ORM class def nor an ORM interface def or anything.. Could someone enlighten me on where that magic happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just have a

```
class ORM extends ORM_Core {}
```

somewhere in your code? This removes the need to use any of the loader code.

You'll also need Kohana_Exception, the Database library (and appropraite driver), Kohana::config(), Kohana::auto_load(), Kohana::log() methods (search Database.php for those).

Kohana is a great MVC framework, but not really designed to be taken apart in chunks like that. You may want to also investigate [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), another ORM for PHP (that IS designed to be stand-alone)

Comment: Yup, this is correct. Just digging through the code to find what I need. It's slightly more difficult since the needed include files aren't "required" at the top, but no complaints when I get the free code.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that Kohana uses magic class loading so that if a defined class with an _Core extention doesn't exist as a class

i.e. ORM_Core exists, but ORM doesn't, so Kohana will magically define an ORM class
Since the package uses 100% magic class loading.

In case anyone is interested, I'm documenting my finds here so everyone can find it later:

```
From Kohana.php in the system directory:

<-- snip if ($extension = self::find_file($type, self::$configuration['core']['extension_prefix'].$class))
{
// Load the extension
require $extension;
}
elseif ($suffix !== 'Core' AND class_exists($class.'_Core', FALSE))
{
// Class extension to be evaluated
$extension = 'class '.$class.' extends '.$class.'_Core { }';
-->

<-- snip

// Transparent class extensions are handled using eval. This is
// a disgusting hack, but it gets the job done.
eval($extension);

-->
```

So it does an eval..

Answer (score 1):

Zak, check Maintainable framework's ORM. http://framework.maintainable.com/mvc/3_model.php#c3.7
Read thoroughly, I am sure you'll like it. I post this in more detail in:
[What is the easiest to use ORM framework for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220229/what-is-the-easiest-to-use-orm-framework-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

http://obando.com.ve/2009/04/29/modelado-orm-rapido-y-facil/

That is all your need!!