# PHP ORM frameworks with features similar to ADO.NET Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: php, .net, frameworks, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm coming from .NET world back to PHP for some side projects. I am comfortable with PHP as a language, but am kind of lost in many PHP frameworks available today. Back in the days I did PHP we just wrote SQL queries, so I have no idea what is possible with PHP today in terms of ORM, therefore the question.

I got used to creating my database models using ADO.NET Entity Framework Code First and I like this approach, so I am looking for a PHP ORM framework with similar set of features.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you are searching a framework with something like AR and CRUD.
I think almost every more famous PHP framework have this options.

Anyway, I am using [Yii framework](http://yiiframework.com/) and I can say it's one of the best options, but you can surf a little to see which framework can fit your requirements.

You can create DB with table relations etc, and the generator will create your models + relations for the Active Record. Also CRUD generator can create and the View/Controller part.

Answer (score 3):

You should review current PHP ORM frameworks, you may find something that they offer that the ADO.Net framework does not.

[What is the easiest to use ORM framework for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220229/what-is-the-easiest-to-use-orm-framework-for-php)

This stack question is very detailed around your question: [Good PHP ORM Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library).

Everyone has an opinion, some better than others.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel ORM](http://www.propelorm.org/)